# Bash: only display lines after a certain time in a file with timestamps

Tags: bash

I'm running a background script that involves reading a log file every 5 minutes formatted like this

```
21:25:57 [INFO] event from 5 minutes ago
21:26:54 [INFO] potentially relevant event
21:28:26 [INFO] some event
21:30:06 [INFO] another event
```

except I only want to look at a the lines that were printed within the last 5 minutes. Essentially I need to find the line where `date -s "$logdate" +%s <= date -d "5 min ago" +%s` closest to the end of the file and ignore all the lines before it.

Unfortunately there are no dates in the timestamps, so it makes it tricky in that the timestamps will recur every day unless I restart the server and reset the log (I'd prefer not to). Using `tac` instead of `cat` might be more effective since I only care about the lines starting from the end of the file.

Comment: What's your question? What part do you need help with? Your `tac` idea is promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU date:

```
$ date +%T
04:56:32
$ date -d "5 min ago" +%T
04:51:45
```

And you can do:

```
tac logfile | awk -v start=$(date -d "5 min ago" +%T) '$1 < start {exit} 1' | tac
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly! I should probably familiarize myself with `awk` more, it worked pretty well here.